# Showing single file download and multiple file download options?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, tables, options, download

**Background**
We are creating wireframes for a website that acts as a repository for where users can download various files. Users should be allowed to download one file at a time and also multiple files at a time. This varies according to the individual user.

Access to the end users, unfortunately, is limited. We might get access to them, but that isn't certain.

**Concern**
How do we clearly show that the user has the option of downloading a single file quickly as well as downloading multiple files at one time, without the multiple CTAs being confusing to the user?

**First Idea**

- The user can select the Download icon in the rightmost column to
  quickly download any one file
- The user can select multiple files to download via the checkboxes in the leftmost column while the text on the orange buttons updates ("Download 1 Selected File", "Download 2 Selected Files", etc). Then they click the orange button to batch download multiple files
- When no files are checked, the orange button reads "Select Files to Download"

[image: Wireframe example - Multi select buttons version]

**Second Idea**

- The user can select the Download icon in the rightmost column to
  quickly download any one file
- The user can select multiple files to download via the checkboxes in the leftmost column while the text on the floating bottom bar updates ("Download 1 Selected File", "Download 2 Selected Files", etc). Then they click the bottom bar to batch download multiple files
- When no files are checked, the text in the bottom bar reads "Select Files to Download"
  [image: Wireframe example - floating bottom bar version]

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution : I gave you 2 options based on your requirement you can use it.

The first option have 2 different scenario as shown below. When user wants to download single file definitely they will click on download icon. But when user selects multiple files to download, that time if you enable the download the icon then user might be confused that after selecting what to do because download icon is also enable and you are displaying external button also.

So what I have done here, when user selects multiple file then download icon get disabled and button named "Download (no.)selected files" will appeared at the top as well as bottom of the table. So with this button user can download the multiple files. (Here 2 buttons are just for the convenience of the user when table listing is too large than they no need to scroll up the page to download the selected files.

[image]

And the second option is as shown below. It doesn't have download icon. Only button will be there. So user has to select check box whether they want to download single file or multiple files.

[image]

Simple ! Easy to Understand !

Comment: I would add this "select all" checkbox as well as a search function, so the user could first use a search name relevant to him and then if there's lot of related documents, he doesn't need to tick every single box.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if the end users are a particular group who will frequently access the site, or whether they're likely to be 'one off' visitors. If they're frequent visitors they will quickly work out they can download a single file quickly or batch download multiple files, so it's really not going to be a problem. Evenso, I would:

- go with the first option
- ensure the orange button appears at both the top and bottom of the list
- change the original orange button label so that it reads "Select file(s) to download"

If they're likely to be infrequent users, then a simple instruction above the list (i.e. above the orange button) would address this, but I really don't think it will be an issue. However, if you were that concerned about it, you could:

- Add a simple instruction above the orange button, something like: *Click the Download icon on the right to download files one by one. To download multiple files, tick the boxes on the left and click on the orange 'Download selected files' button.*
- Change the button so that it reads "Download selected files", but have it disabled so that it does not work unless a check box is selected